# How to use People Picker and True Rich Text, cross browser

Tags: list, people-picker, field-controls

I have a list being deployed as part of a site definition. I need to have a custom web-part with controls that are able to fill in list data.

SharePoint doesn't have an out of the box people-picker control, and the Rich Text box (InputFormTextBox) is IE only.

How do I create a form which can be styled and allows for full-featured use of these SharePoint controls? I can't use InfoPath, because that creates a dependency, and you can't link it dynamically to a List at the SPWeb level (and I'm not sure you can add one in Visual Studio as part of a Site Definition anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both SharePoint 2007 and in SharePoint 2010, you can use the PeopleEditor (People Picker) control from SharePoint.  You simply refer to it like any other custom ASP.NET control.  For 2007, there is an MSDN blog about it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ekraus/archive/2008/02/06/use-peopleeditor-people-picker-in-sharepoint-custom-app-dev.aspx.  For 2010, you would just need to update the references to the 14 DLLs.

As far as a rich text editor, I would suggest using one of the many freely available JavaScript controls (like TinyMCE).

Comment: Never knew about PeopleEditor! Thanks. I wanted to stay away from JQuery, but it beats trying to embed and dual-deploy a Telerik control or something of the like.